# defaultValue in AOR-dependent-input

Tags: admin-on-rest

I want to set defaultValue for field in aor-dependent-input,
I already set defaultValue for `ReferenceInput`, but how can I set defaultValue for `DependentInput` using `SubGenreInput`

Here is my code:

```
<Create {...propsEdit} title=" " actions="">
<SimpleForm  redirect={"/caregiver/" + cid}>
    {/*<ReferenceArrayInput>*/}
    <DisabledInput source="user" defaultValue={cid} label="Caregiver ID"/>
    <ReferenceInput label="Centre" source="centre" defaultValue={this.props.record.student.centre.id} reference="centre" sort={{ field: 'name', order: 'ASC' }} allowEmpty>
        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
    </ReferenceInput>
    <DependentInput dependsOn="centre">
        <SubGenreInput source="current_group" optionText="label" optionValue="id" type="classgroup"/>
    </DependentInput>
    <DependentInput dependsOn="current_group" defaultValue={this.props.record.student.id}>
        <SubGenreInput source="student_id" optionText="fullname" optionValue="id" type="student"/>
    </DependentInput>
    {/*</ReferenceArrayInput>*/}
    <RadioButtonGroupInput source="account_type"  defaultValue={10} choices={[
        { id: 10, name: 'Caregiver' },
        { id: 20, name: 'Guardian' },
    ]} optionText="name" optionValue="id" />
    <TextInput source="relationship" label="Relationship"/>
</SimpleForm>
```

Interface:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFHKC.png

// I'm not allow to post the images :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue which will be addressed by version `1.3.0` of `admin-on-rest`. In the mean time you can use this workaround:

```
<DependentInput source="appointmentTimeslot" dependsOn="planned" defaultValue={1}>
    <ReferenceInput source="appointmentTimeslot" reference="timeslots" allowEmpty={true} >
        <SelectInput optionText="name" optionValue="id" />
    </ReferenceInput>
</DependentInput>
```

Note that we specified `source` on both the `DependentInput` component and its child. The `defaultValue`, however, is specified on the `DependentInput` component only.

This workaround won't work if you pass multiple children to the `DependentInput` component.